# Building simple http-header for Junit test

Tags: java, servlets, junit, mocking

I'm trying to test a `HttpServletRequest` and for that I have used  [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) as follow:

```
HttpServletRequest  mockedRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

now before putting the http-request in `assert` methods I just want to build a simple http header as below without starting a real server:

```
x-real-ip:127.0.0.1
host:example.com
x-forwarded-for:127.0.0.1
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
cookie:JSESSIONID=<session_ID>
```

can some one help how can I build such a test header? thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You can just stub the calls to request.getHeaders etc. or if you can add a dependency, [Spring-test](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/3.2.0.RELEASE) has a `MockHttpServletRequest` that you could use (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#mock-objects-servlet))

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.addHeader("x-real-ip","127.0.0.1");
```

Or you could build your own implementation which allows you to set headers.

Comment: the project is a maven web project.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer uses `MockHttpServletRequest`. 
If one would like to use `Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class)` , then could stub the request as follows.

```
final HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
when(request.getHeader("host")).thenReturn("stackoverflow.com");
when(request.getHeader("x-real-ip")).thenReturn("127.0.0.1");
```